# Consumed memory per process

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

How can I get the current total allocated memory so far (in a Linux process in `C/C++ (gcc)`)?

Comment: Within your own program? Or outside (then maybe using `htop` or similar tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing [`/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/$PID/maps`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.4.1/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#L315) . Look for a line marked `[heap]`.

Answer (score 0):

I like Rob's answer, but here's a possible alternative. If you can afford the run time cost, you can use valgrind with the [massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) tool.

Comment: Thank you, but I need a runtime checking from my own program.